# invoke non-const member function pointer on object

Tags: c++

I have a problem invoking some non const member Functions on an object.
The idea is to invoke member functions on given objects. This works well with const functions, but if I have some non-const functions and try to change a value inside of them the program crashes with exit code=3221225477

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
struct Test
{
    int testVal = 0;
    /* Call a given function on 10 objects */
    void callFunctionOnMultipleObjects(void (Test::*func)())
    {
        for(int i=0;i < 10; i++)
        {
            Test *test;
            Test::callTestFunction = func;
            Test::callTestFunction(test);
        }
        std::cout << "**************** \n";
    }

    /* Test Functions */
    void testFunction1(){
        std::cout << "some const/static action \n";
    }
    void testFunction2(){
        std::cout << "non const/static action \n";
        /* The Program crashes here */
        testVal ++;
    }
    std::function<void(Test *)> callTestFunction;
};
int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.callFunctionOnMultipleObjects(&Test::testFunction1);
    test.callFunctionOnMultipleObjects(&Test::testFunction2);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change my Code so I can call non-const functions like this ?

Comment: exit code=3221225477 is 0xC0000005, which means - access violation. Did you try stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes and it crashes where I commented at testVal ++

Comment: So, did you investigate the values of local variables? Knowing where it crashes is only one side of the story..

Comment: It crashes at the first try to change the value

Comment: Please re-read my comment. Your latest comment is unrelated to what I asked.

Comment: Okay it crashes because Test *test is not allowed, instead I have to initialize Test *test = new Test().

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking both `testFunction1` `testFunction2` on the object pointed to by uninitialized `Test *test;` variable causing undefined behavior in both cases. Call to `testFunction2` attempts to access object storage by changing `testVal` so it apparently leads to crash. You should supply a pointer to a valid object instead:

```
callTestFunction(this); // no need for Test:: prefix
```

Also both `testFunction1` `testFunction2` are not `const`, you need to actually add qualifier:

```
void testFunction1() const
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not exactly the goal I want to achieve. I want to change the value of the object I generated in the loop.I figured out that Test *test = new Test() works, it was a silly mistake.